# How to put bottom navigation bar above the navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oop

I'm new to coding and I want to implement a navigation drawer wherein there is a bottom navigation bar above it not below. I'm making a drawer similar to discord's navigation drawer. Can somebody teach me a few tricks? thankyou

Comment: Ideally Drawer should come above the bottom bar because if you put bottom bar above Drawer then the elements at the bottom of Drawer will not be visible

Answer (score 0):

You can implement bottom navigation bar and navigation drawer in one component. This component is BottomAppBar.
[Click here to learn about bottom appbars](https://material.io/components/app-bars-bottom/android)